# facebookConnectPlugin is not defined (ngCordova, Ionic app)

Tags: angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework

I'm trying to add native fb connect to my ionic app.

I'm using:
- Ionic
- ngCordova
- http://ngcordova.com/docs/plugins/facebook/

This is my code:

```
angular.module('starter.controllers', ['ngCordova'])

.config(function($cordovaFacebookProvider) {
var appID = 123456789;
var version = "v2.0"; // or leave blank and default is v2.0
$cordovaFacebookProvider.browserInit(appID, version);
})
```

Which leads to this error >

```
Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module starter due to:
Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module starter.controllers due to:
ReferenceError: facebookConnectPlugin is not defined
at browserInit (http://localhost:8100/lib/ngCordova/dist/ng-cordova.js:1576:7)
at http://localhost:8100/js/controllers.js:6:30
at Object.invoke (http://localhost:8100/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:11994:17)
at runInvokeQueue (http://localhost:8100/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:11900:35)
at http://localhost:8100/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:11909:11
at forEach (http://localhost:8100/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:8147:20)
at loadModules (http://localhost:8100/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:11890:5)
at http://localhost:8100/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:11907:40
at forEach (http://localhost:8100/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:8147:20)
at loadModules (http://localhost:8100/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:11890:5)
```

Tried a couple of things but without any positive result:
- When I build it and run it on my device the app displays a blank screen

- Tried the normal cordova js code:
- Changed $cordovaFacebookProvider to $cordovaFacebook (based on this thread: 
  forum.ionicframework.com/t/unknown-provider-cordovaprovider/13305/3
- And this is a another related thread, but doesn't help me thought..
  forum.ionicframework.com/t/does-ng-crodova-has-facebook-login/9163

I already have a prototype working with the fb auth in the in-app-browser. But I really want to have a native fb connect functionality.

Comment: Is the plugin correctly installed? run `ionic plugin list`, or try reinstalling the plugin

Comment: Looks like it:
com.phonegap.plugins.PushPlugin 2.4.0 "PushPlugin"

com.phonegap.plugins.facebookconnect 0.11.0 "Facebook Connect"

org.apache.cordova.camera 0.3.4 "Camera"
org.apache.cordova.console 0.2.12 "Console"
org.apache.cordova.inappbrowser 0.5.5-dev "InAppBrowser"

Comment: Any success? I'm stuck on this problem too.

Answer (score 5):

i found a way to resolve this issue.

Thanks to this thread : https://github.com/driftyco/ng-cordova/issues/446

and this tutorial : https://github.com/Wizcorp/phonegap-facebook-plugin/blob/master/platforms/browser/README.md

1st step : Don't forget the `<div id="fb-root"></div>` after ur body.

2nd step : I added facebookConnectPlugin to my bower dependencies

See my bower.json :

```
"dependencies": {
    "angular-google-maps": "~2.0.13",
    "google-map": "~0.4.1",
    "facebook-connect-plugin": "https://cdn.rawgit.com/Wizcorp/phonegap-facebook-plugin/master/facebookConnectPlugin.js"
}
```

See my app.config + code to init:

```
app.config(function ($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider, $ionicConfigProvider, $animateProvider, $httpProvider, $cordovaFacebookProvider) {

var appID = 597135743751760;
var version = "v2.0"; // or leave blank and default is v2.0
$cordovaFacebookProvider.browserInit(appID, version);
```

$cordovaFacebookProvider call facebookConnectPlugin()

3th step : After changing this dependencies, don't forget to call bower update from ur CLI.
[image: bower update example]

4th step : Include the new facebookblablabla.js in your index.html.

it can be

```
<script src='bower_components/facebook-connect-plugin/index.js'></script>
```

for me it was

```
<script src='lib/facebook-connect-plugin/index.js'></script>
```

5th step :  add in the Valid OAuth redirect URIs field at your Facebook App :
http://static.ak.facebook.com/connect/xd_arbiter/

Hope it works for you :) !

Comment: gave me TypeError: Cannot read property 'browserInit' of undefined

Comment: Have you add $cordovaFacebookProvider in you app.config injection ? 
app.config(function ($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider, $ionicConfigProvider, $cordovaFacebookProvider)

Answer (score 0):

My answer is not providing a solution for your issue but an advice.

Why using facebook Cordova when you can use HelloJS? 
faceBook Cordova is platform dependant, much slower as it runs cordova true node.js and not evolutive.

HelloJS permits to integer various Oauth2 authentication very easily including, facebook / google / twitter / instagram ...

Without to tell that the compilation for facebook cordova is very tricky with the facebook key app. On HelloJS, this is only a parameter that you can easily change.

Comment: sorry but the JS based solutions all have a heavy drawback: they require the user to sign in again if he has not signed in via his browser. This is not something that's expected by the user and provides an unsatisfactory experience for hybrid apps :(

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if someone still stuck with this thing then please follow the method mentioned my @Alexy and then edit the 'lib/facebook-connect-plugin/index.js' file line from :

```
if(cordova.platformId === 'browser')
```

to

```
if(!window.cordova || (window.cordova && window.cordova.platformId === 'browser'))
```

Hope this Helps :)

Comment: this doesn't really help because the "else" clause tries to load the facebook plugin for cordova which is already (at this point) determined not to exist.